# sphinx не ищет в тексте емайл адреса

Tags: sphinx

Сделал индекс, слова русские ищет, а вот адреса целиком не хочет искать, типа info@mail.ru. А вот если ищу mail.ru - он его разбивает на mail и ru, и - ищет.

настройки стандартные
версия 2.3

может  какую то настройку специальную забыл указать?

Answer (score 0):

вобщем обновил я сфинк, точнее скачал последнюю версию 3 и заработало как надо. Видимо по умолчанию при установке через репозиторий ubuntu - скачивается старая версия.
Проблема решена, ищет как надо